# Can I include Retina images in GitHub files?

Tags: github, markdown

Is it currently possible to specify a Retina image with the current GitHub-flavoured Markdown? Or an image size, which would let standard resolution devices scale the resource?

It's not a big deal, but it would add a nice touch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown is a strict superset of HTML, so you should be able to just make the HTML tag explicitly and set the size how you want. See http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/image-tag.html.

Comment: Not an answer at all. Actually Miculas asking does github markdown engine supports something like <img srcset="imageurl 2x"/>
And the answer is no :(